# Unfortunately deleted all users in mysql.user table. How can i create new user

Tags: mysql

I am deleted all users in mysql.user table. Now I am unable to connect with mysql. How can I create a new user or how to restart mysql with out losing my data.

Thank you very much.

Comment: do you have root access?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16215/mysql-users-deleted

Answer (score 1):

Connect to the mysqld server using MySQL and run:

1. `UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('password') WHERE User='root';`
2. `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Comment: Thank you for reply. But i am not able connect mysql.

Comment: Login on server using root credentials                                               
1.service mysql restart --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking,                   
2.mysql  and press enter on command line  3.)CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';   4.)GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'newuser'@'localhost';     5.) FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Comment: service mysql restart --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking command not found error.